Customize text color for inserted/deleted lines in monaco diff editor
I am currently trying to create a diff editor where the text color of inserted/deleted lines changes.
Changing the background color is easy enough with the 'diffEditor.insertedTextBackground'
and 'diffEditor.removedTextBackground'  colors as documented here.
But I haven't been able to figure out how to actually change the text color.
I tried using the tokens markup.inserted.diff and markup.delete.diff that I saw being used here. But they didn't seem to work.

As far as I know, this is not currently possible. It is not even possible to create a custom tokenizer to handle this, because the tokenizers are defined declaratively.
